# Expected number of connections for a graph

Tags: graph-theory

If I have a graph with 10 nodes and probability of an edge being 0.6, what is the expected number of 'common friends' of two nodes A and B? e.g. by 1 common friend I mean that for Node A and B (just both of them), only one of the remaining nodes connect to both A and B.

I already have a correct solution which is 1*P(1)+2*P(2)+3*P(3)+...+8*P(8) = 2.xx (where xx is hidden because of homework reasons) (pls inform me if i should reveal the numbers)

But... there is a much simpler solution. Someone I know has the answer and the clue is it's composed of a mere 2-3 terms, the last one ending with a number (9 i think). Can anyone give me a hint on how to solve it?

P.S. please inform me if there is anything I need to clarify or add. thanks!

Comment: Do you mean, $C$ is a common friend of $A$ and $B$ if it is connected to both of them?

Comment: @Goos Yep, that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way to do it is to remember that expectation is additive.  That is, suppose the nodes are $A, B, C, D, E$.  Then the expected total number of common friends is the equal to the sum of the expected chance that $C$ is a common friend, plus the expected chance that $D$ is a common friend, plus the expected  chance that $E$ is a common friend.

So with $10$ nodes, you have $8$ candidates for a common friend.
Each candidate has a $(.6) \cdot (.6)$ chance of being a common friend of $A$ and $B$ (why?) To find the total expected number of common friends of $A$ and $B$, just add up the values for each of the $8$ candidates.

Comment: Thanks! It produced the same right answer and it sorta makes sense, except my logic is if there is A,B,C,D,E I would consider 1 friend as 0.6^2 and two friends as (0.6^2)*2 so that would cause the answer for 10 nodes to be 0.6^2*(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8) but why is this not the case? Why can we just multiply by 8?

Comment: @user3511965 I am not sure I follow your logic.  You are only counting the friends of both $A$ and $B$, so you don't do $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + \cdots + 8$.  Instead, for each of the nodes, it is only counted once, because you are only counting the ways it is friends with $A$ and $B$.